# Python type exists

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have to check whether passed object type exists in python using boost python library:

```
// bp = boost::python
bool TypeExists(const std::string &typeName)
{
    bp::object ret = bp::exec(
            (boost::format("'%1%' in globals()") % typeName).str().c_str()
    );
    return bp::extract<bool>(ret);
}
```

So, in this code I run python expression which looks like: `'TypeName' in globals()`. This should return object with Boolean type. But extract always returns 0. Type 100% exists because in next line after `TypeExists` call I create the object of this type. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *exec* executes Python code and returns **execution result** (whether it executed or had errors); and you need the result of expression evaluation.

You must use **eval** here to get expression evaluation result.

```
bp::object ret = bp::eval(...)
```

This is described in [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/doc/v2/exec.html#eval-spec).

Comment: Maybe you know, with `eval` it returns an error that `global` doesn't exist. What could be wrong?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just had to pass as a second argument my global namespace.